# Redux - How to get data from store and post it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, html-select

Newbie to Redux here, I have tried to follow a couple tutorials and I am not clear of how Redux actually works. It was mentioned that the store of Redux is to store the state of the whole tree. I have created and used actions, reducers, and store for my program and it works.

The question is, how do I retrieve what is in the store? Lets say after updating my component, how can I retrieve the value inside the component and to post it?

How can I know what changed in my dropdown list and to retrieve it?

Full code in Sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-goldberg-1pogb

store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './RootReducer';

export default function configureStore() {
 return createStore(
  rootReducer,
   applyMiddleware(thunk)
 );
}
```

ProductsList.js

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchProducts } from "./SimpleActions";

class ProductList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selecteditems: '',
            unitPrice: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts());
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if(prevState.selecteditems !== this.state.selecteditems)
        {
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                unitPrice: ((state.selecteditems * 1).toFixed(2))
            }));
        }
    }

  render() {
    const { error, loading, products } = this.props;

    if (error) {
      return <div>Error! {error.message}</div>;
    }

    if (loading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <select
            name="sel"
            className="sel"
            value={this.state.selecteditems}
            onChange={(e) => 
                this.setState({selecteditems: e.target.value})}
        >
            {products.map(item => 
            <option key={item.productID} value={item.unitPrice}>
                {item.itemName}
            </option>
            )}
        </select>

        <p>Unit Price: RM {this.state.unitPrice} </p>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const products = state.productsReducer.items;
  const loading = state.productsReducer.loading;
  const error = state.productsReducer.error;
  return {
      products,
      loading,
      error,
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductList);
```

SimpleAction.js

```
export function fetchProducts() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
        return fetch('http://localhost:55959/api/products')
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
            dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(results));
            return results;
        })
        .catch(error => dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error)));
    };
}

function handleErrors(response) {
    if(!response.ok) {
        throw Error (response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}

export const FETCHPRODUCTS_BEGIN = 'FETCHPRODUCTS_BEGIN';
export const FETCHPRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'FETCHPRODUCTS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCHPRODUCTS_FAILURE = 'FETCHPRODCUTS_FAILURE';

export const fetchProductsBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCHPRODUCTS_BEGIN
});

export const fetchProductsSuccess = products => ({
    type: FETCHPRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
    payload: {products}
});

export const fetchProductsFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCHPRODUCTS_FAILURE,
    payload: {error}
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass your action handlers to connect function

```js
connect(mapStateToProps,{actions})(ProductList).
```

Comment: After passing the actions to the connect function, is there a way to read what I have passed to the state?

Comment: You can use Redux DevTools. It's a plugin in chrome. To use it, add

`const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;`

`const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)));`

to your index.js

Comment: Also `import { compose } from 'redux';`

Answer (score 0):

> how do I retrieve what is in the store? Lets say after updating my component, how can I retrieve the value inside the component and to post it?

if you want to see how is store change, you can add redux-logger to middleware to see that. when store change, it's likely a props change, you can handle this in function componentDidUpdate.

> How can I know what changed in my dropdown list and to retrieve it?

values in dropdown is controlled by "const products = state.productsReducer.items;", productsReducer is controlled by actions you passed in dispatch like this: "this.props.dispatch(fetchProducts());".

I think you should add redux-logger to know more how to redux work, it show on console step by step. It will help you learn faster than you think :D

Comment: Thank you, I will look into redux-logger. Do you have any idea on how to post the values that are changed?

Comment: I have added redux-logger, it shows clearly the prev state and the next state, but when I changes the item on the dropdown list it does not show anything. How can I make it show in the log, and to store it somewhere?

Comment: cause you're changing state in component, it is not on store redux:  "onChange={(e) => 
                this.setState({selecteditems: e.target.value})}". You should write a new function to set state and update value to store like you update productsReducer.

Comment: just seem like you doing with productsReducer, create  new action, new reducer, add reducer to store, call dispatch when you change value dropdown.

Comment: So for my onChange it would be this.props.something instead of this.setState?

Comment: No, you only change state in component you created, not props value. Props value you get in store via connect redux, you want to change it, you must call dispatch to change, it's one of different things between redux and react.

Comment: I get what you mean, I know that I should make use of the redux function for the onChange. Just that I don't know how to get there haha, will keep on researching

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve it you forgot the `selecteditems`

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const products = state.productsReducer.items;
  const loading = state.productsReducer.loading;
  const error = state.productsReducer.error;
  const selecteditems = state.prodcuts.selecteditems;
  return {
    products,
    loading,
    error,
    selecteditems
  };
};
```

To change it you should connect another function like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onChangeDropdownSelection: (selected)=> dispatch(actions.setSelectedDropdown(selected))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the connecting another function? I don't understand how the code function